# C++ Eclipse in Windows, when the run button is clicked nothing is showing in the console

Tags: cygwin, eclipse, c++

I am in the middle of the process for installing Eclipse CDT in a Windows environment, and I got everything working, except when I press the "run" button nothing is showing up in the Eclipse console.

I have installed Cygwin with GCC and G++, "make" command, and everything Eclipse required.

The "build" button in Eclipse works like charm. When I press the "build" button, the correct executable file is created, and I can confirm this by going into project folder and run the executable in Windows.

But the problem is that when I press the "run" button, the Eclipse console shows nothing. I have correctly set my run configuration to where "C/C++ Application" is pointing to a correct binary.  It is saying program is terminated, even if my main is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    puts("Hello World!!!");
    cout << "hey" << endl;
    cout << "TESTGIN" << endl;
    system("read -p hello");
    return 0;
}
```